# How to create a Dynamic measure that only calculate filtered rows

Tags: dynamic, filter, powerbi, measure

I want to create a measure that return **distinctcount(ordernumbers)** where every row **is "Sant" Divided by the distinctcount(ordernumbers)**.

The measure should adapt the calculation by chosen filter.

[image]

This is my temporary solution which doesn't adapt when I am applying filters.

```
Availability = 
VAR __CountSIRowsPerOrder =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(Sheet1);
        [Ordernumber] = EARLIER([Ordernumber]) &&
        [Available] = True))
VAR __CountRowsPerOrder =
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(Sheet1);
        [Ordernumber] = EARLIER([Ordernumber])))
RETURN
IF(__CountRowsPerOrder = __CountSIRowsPerOrder; True; False)

FilterAvailability (measure) = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Ordernumber]);
    FILTER(Sheet1;[Availability] = True))
    /
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Blad2[Ordernumber])
```

Comment: Your solution ignores filters, because you told it to do so. Instead of [ALL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) you may want to use [ALLSELECTED()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax).

Comment: I tried with ALLSELECTED, but it seems that EARLIER still calculates on the complete table.